# MS bot framework session.send cannot send array of messages

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using MS bot framework Node version 3.8.1
As stated by the comment in line 1216 [Ms botbuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/7b70cfd/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L1216)

session.send should be able to send an array of messages. 
However when I try this very simple code

```
session.send(["this","that","last"])
```

I observe that only the last message "last" is delivered to the user. No errors thrown. Any ideas of the cause or is it wrong documentation? Any way to send an array of messages to a user?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, when you pass an [array](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/modules/_botbuilder_d_.html#textormessagetype) to [`session.send()`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#send), it doesn't send everything inside of the array. It selects one from random and sends it to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Interesting because comment inside the source code explicitly says "to send message(s)", if it always send 1 only why say messages? Maybe better documentation and/or better explanation in the source code could help. So about the second part of the question, is there a way to send multiple messages to the same user in one line? Thanks again

Comment: Hm... if you mean in one line of code I don't believe there is currently a way to do so. Iterating over an array of responses works, but not what you're looking for...

Comment: Also, I'll get a pull request going on changing the comment to bring it in line with the documentation. Thanks for pointing that out!